# VBA How to Ignore empty cells to be highlighted

Tags: vba, excel

With a help of a member here i have solved a problem.
The problem was

1. ColumnB values is green in when common with ColumnO  values.
2. ColumnB values is yellow in when it is not common with ColumnO values.
3. ColumnO values is red in when its not in ColumnB.

Now i am facing a new problem, It's in #3, when columnO is highlighting red, it is also highlighting empty cells. May be because there is no empty cell in  ColumnB but it has some empty cells between values in sheet2 columnO, and i want those empty cells to be there. Any idea how to ignore empty cells to be highlighted?

```
Dim addr1 As String, addr2 As String
With Worksheets("Only WR")
    With .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        addr1 = .Cells(1).Address(False, True)
        addr2 = .Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, True)
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
          Formula1:="=AND(" & addr2 & "=TEXT(,), ISNUMBER(MATCH(" & addr1 & ", 'Only WR'!$O:$O, 0)))")
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End With
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
          Formula1:="=NOT(LEN(" & addr2 & "))")
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End With
    End With
End With

With Worksheets("Only WR")
    With .Range(.Cells(1, "O"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp))
        addr1 = .Cells(1).Address(False, True)
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
          Formula1:="=ISNA(MATCH(" & addr1 & ", 'Only WR'!$B:$B, 0))")
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End With
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand your problem. But in a selection if you want to select only cells with constants you can try this VBA code

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this below your last "End With".

```
Columns("O").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).ClearFormats
```